# Way to apply a model validation to ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have some validation written in my model in the clean method like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    foo = ....
    bar = ...

    def clean(self):
        (logic that should be applied to all instances of MyModels to validate)
```

And I want to use this logic (rather than a ModelForm.clean) to validate a model form for MyModel.  I expected it would look something like:

```
def my_view(request):

    ...

    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
    try:
        # validate
        form.instance.clean()
        form.instance.save()
    except ValidationError as e:
        validation_error = e # ???
```

But this doesn't work.  The two reasons I want to do this are

1. I want the validation to be applied to all MyModels, so this seems like the most DRY way to do it.
2. I want to show the text of the model ValidationError to the user.

I have looked all around and haven't found any examples or explanations of how to do validation in this way.  Is there a better way that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't catch ValidationErrors like that. All ValidationErrors are collected in a dict in form.errors.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            validation_errors = form.errors
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to explicitly invoke your `Model` validation. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#validation-on-a-modelform):

> Just like normal form validation, model form validation is triggered implicitly when
>   calling is_valid() or accessing the errors attribute.... Model validation... 
>   is triggered from within the form validation step.

So just validate your form in the regular way (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) or Jay's answer).